# Puppet cannot find class

Tags: puppet

Hi I'm new to puppet and I'm trying to make a test class, but when I run `puppet apply-t` I get error `Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::heroes` for 
under my test directory I have

```
.
├── examples
│   ├── init.pp
│   └── superhero.pp
└── manifests
    ├── init.pp
    └── superhero.pp

2 directories, 4 files
```

in my `superhero.pp` under manifest the code reads

```
class heroes {
    user { 'thor':
        ensure => present,
    }
}
```

in my `superhero.pp` under example the code reads

```
include heroes
```

Not sure why when I run `puppet apply --noop superheroes.pp` under examples that error shows up?

Here is my complete tree under modules

```
├── hosts
│   ├── examples
│   │   └── init.pp
│   └── manifests
│       └── init.pp
├── nginx
│   ├── examples
│   │   └── init.pp
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── default.conf
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── nginx.conf
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifests
│       ├── index.html
│       └── init.pp
├── test
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── admins.pp
│   │   ├── init.pp
│   │   └── superhero.pp
│   └── manifests
│       ├── admins.pp
│       ├── init.pp
│       └── superhero.pp
└── users
├── examples
│   ├── admins.pp
│   └── init.pp
└── manifests
    ├── admins.pp
    └── init.pp
```

Comment: If you want to let the autoloader find your class and allow you to `include` it, you should put it in a module. See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#location

Comment: Isn't my include inside my module(examples-superhero.pp)?

Comment: No, modules go under `modules/`, e.g. `modules/heroes/manifests/superheroes.pp`, then you could `include heroes::superheroes` from somewhere else. (Also make sure to name the class according to the module / file name - `heroes/manifests/superheroes.pp` would be `class heroes::superheroes { }`.  https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html#module-layout

Comment: Thanks much more clear now.

Answer (score 11):

I think there may be two problems

1. First is that when running `puppet apply superheroes.pp` in the `examples` directory, it doesn't know where to look for other modules (like `heroes` you `include`). To know where to look for modules, [you need to give it a *modulepath*](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.3.1/man/apply.html#EXAMPLE):

   puppet apply --modulepath=/path/to/modules --noop superhero.pp
2. The other problem is the location of `heroes` class that you state is located in `test/manifests/superhero.pp`. The rules for where Puppet is trying to find classes are described [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_namespaces.html#autoloader-behavior) and [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#location). Unless you're doing something less usual such as defining a class inside another class, puppet will use the following rules to locate the class:

   1. The first segment (segments are separated by `::`) identifies module.
   2. If there is only one segment, file name is `init.pp`, otherwise file name is the last segment with `.pp` extension
   3. The segments in between denote subdirectories under `manifests` directory.
   4. The path where puppet will look is

      ```
      <modulepath>/<module name>/manifests/<subdirectories>.../<file name>.pp
      ```

   Here is an example from the documentation:

   ```
       == class name ==        == path ==
       apache                  <module path>/apache/manifests/init.pp
       apache::mod             <module path>/apache/manifests/mod.pp
       apache::mod::passenger  <module path>/apache/manifests/mod/passenger.pp
   ```

Returning back to your question: Upon `include heroes`, puppet will look in `<modulepath>/heroes/manifests/init.pp`. Conversely, to make puppet look in `test/manifests/superhero.pp`, you would need to include class `test::superhero`.

Comment: puppet moved your resources on you, can you update the links?